# Algorithm for the most effective path through simple 2D map

Tags: algorithm, 2d, path-finding

I have a simple 2D map of mine where every tile is walkable and mineable.
Miner can walk in 4 directions and can mine tile under him and in every +1(distance) tile. He can also start and end where he wants(these can differ), entrance is not specified. He just needs to mine everything.

Is there any clever way to compute the most effective way to walk through whole mine? Less steps mean more effectiveness.

My only idea so far was "brute-force" iteration through all tiles, computing all possible paths, counting steps, and finding the best path.

Thank you for ideas!

Comment: Second link from google: http://www.cokeandcode.com/main/tutorials/path-finding/

Comment: What shape and size does the map have? Or there any obstacles? Could you perhaps post an example of a map?

Answer (score 0):

That is the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), just instead of cities you have mining positions.